# How do you tame a wild animal without being/knowing a beast-master?

Tags: dnd-5e, dnd-adventurers-league, animals

In one of my recent D&D sessions, one of the members of the party (rogue) tamed a wild turkey. Since then, the rest of us have wanted a companion/pet as well (ex: Blood Hawk, Bat, etc.). Are there certain rules for animal-taming? Or is it completely up to the DM? Because with the turkey, they tamed it in one roll.

Please note that none of us are Rangers or beast-masters.

And we are playing in Adventurers League (the DM usually decides whether to use a rule or not).

Comment: @PurpleMonkey I think the fact that OP is playing AL makes this a non-dupe. (Super-)voting to reopen, but feel free to ping me in chat if you disagree and want to pick each other's brains.

Answer (score 4):

## Ask your DM if Animal Handling is right for you

There is no RAW for this, and as this is an AL game, I would advise you to talk to your DM on what he will allow and how he wants to handle this.

As the rogue apparently already managed to tame a turkey, I assume the DM already has a method he likes to use, but if not you can look for ideas at the answers to: [What are the rules for owning and training animals?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/59291/what-are-the-rules-for-owning-and-training-animals).