# Can you have a penguin as a pet?

Tags: dnd-5e, animals

I was wondering if you could have a penguin as a pet and, if so, what are the stats and where do you put it in the character sheet? I'm not taking about an animal companion and I'm not a ranger; I am playing a fighter wizard snow elf.

Comment: What kind of "pet" do you mean in this context? An animal companion that can act in combat like the Ranger's *Beast Master* companion? If so, are you asking in the context of *being* a Beast Master Ranger or gaining an animal companion as another class? A non-combat animal that you just have around? Something else? What rules have you read that makes you think this is or isn't possible? What rules are confusing you? You need to provide us with more details and context as to what you want so we can help answer your question.

Comment: Related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/59291/43856

Comment: Hi Mcallister! Welcome to rpg.se! Take the [tour] and check out [this meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9185/48759) for other places you can find help. You can also ask me with @linksassin here in the comments. Your question has been closed as unclear because it is lacking a few details we need to answer it. If you can [edit] you question to include the information PurpleMonkey suggests that is a good start.

Comment: Are you playing a ranger and want to know if you can have a penguin and your animal companion? If so you should mention that. The part about where to put it on the character sheet is probably a separate question, and it would depend on which version of the character sheet you are using.

Comment: I think answers can reasonably cover *how* one gets a penguin pet, including whether or not it requires being a ranger, and if not whether or not ranger provides additional benefits for pet penguins. Mcallister seems fairly new to the game, and so it is on us to explain these things, not on them to already know how these kinds of things work in D&D 5e. If they already knew that, there’s a pretty good chance that they wouldn’t need to ask the question at all.

Comment: Specifically, see [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/134261/904) to the question this is marked as a duplicate of.